# django css file not loading

Tags: css, django, templates, static

I'm struggling to load my custom.css file to use in my bootstrap template:

error:

```
"GET /static/artdb/css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1785
```

path to custom.css:

```
static/artdb/css/custom.css
```

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
       :
<!-- Custom styles for this template --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "artdb/css/custom.css" %}">
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('artdb/', include('artdb.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
#STATICFILES_DIRS =(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),)
```

any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You need STATICFILES_DIRS settings in development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS= [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'###path to static folder in project###'),STATIC_URL]
```

Comment: ok, 
    STATICFILES_DIRS= [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),STATIC_URL] did it. thanks